# Standard errors of hyperbolic distribution estimates using delta-method?

Tags: distributions, standard-error, fitting, delta-method

I want to calculate the standard errors of a fitted hyperbolic distribution.

In my notation the density is given by
\begin{align*}
H(l;\alpha,\beta,\mu,\delta)&=\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{2\alpha \delta K_1 (\delta\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2})} exp\left(-\alpha\sqrt{\delta^2+(l-\mu)^2}+\beta(l-\mu)\right)
\end{align*}
I am using the HyperbolicDistr package in R. I estimate the parameters via the following command:

```
hyperbFit(mydata,hessian=TRUE)
```

This gives me a wrong parameterization. I change it into my desired parameterization with the `hyperbChangePars(from=1,to=2,c(mu,delta,pi,zeta))` command. Then I want to have the standard errors of my estimates, I can get it for the wrong parameterization with the `summary` command. But this gives me the standard errors for the other parameterization. According to this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55714/standard-errors-of-hyperbfit) I have to use the delta-method (I do *not* want to use bootstrap or cross-validation or so).

The `hyperbFit` code is [here](https://github.com/sjp/GeneralizedHyperbolic/blob/master/R/hyperbFit.R). And the `hyperbChangePars` is [here](https://github.com/sjp/GeneralizedHyperbolic/blob/master/R/hyperbChangePars.R). Therefore I know, that $\mu$ and $\delta$ stay the same. Therefore also the standard errors are the same, right?

For transforming $\pi$ and $\zeta$ into $\alpha$ and $\beta$ I need the relationship between them. According to the code this is done as follows:

```
alpha <- zeta * sqrt(1 + hyperbPi^2) / delta
beta <- zeta * hyperbPi / delta
```

**So how do I have to code the delta-method to get the desired standard errors?**

EDIT: I am using these [data](http://uploadeasy.net/upload/ygvdc.rar).
I first perform the delta-method according to this thread.

```
# fit the distribution

hyperbfitdb<-hyperbFit(mydata,hessian=TRUE)
hyperbChangePars(from=1,to=2,hyperbfitdb$Theta)
summary(hyperbfitdb)
```

`summary(hyperbfitdb)` gives the following output:

```
Data:      mydata 
Parameter estimates:
        pi           zeta         delta           mu    
    0.0007014     1.3779503     0.0186331    -0.0001352 
  ( 0.0938886)  ( 0.9795029)  ( 0.0101284)  ( 0.0035774)
Likelihood:         615.992 
Method:             Nelder-Mead 
Convergence code:   0 
Iterations:         315
```

and `hyperbChangePars(from=1,to=2,hyperbfitdb$Theta)` gives the following output:

```
   alpha.zeta     beta.zeta   delta.delta         mu.mu 
73.9516898823  0.0518715378  0.0186331187 -0.0001352342
```

now I define the variables in the following way:

```
pi<-0.0007014 
lzeta<-log(1.3779503)
ldelta<-log(0.0186331)
```

I now run the code (second edit) and get the following result:

```
> se.alpha
         [,1]
[1,] 13.18457
> se.beta
        [,1]
[1,] 6.94268
```

Is this correct? I am wondering about the following: If I use a bootstrap-algorithm in the following way:

```
B = 1000 # number of bootstraps

alpha<-NA
beta<-NA
delta<-NA
mu<-NA


# Bootstrap
for(i in 1:B){
  print(i)
  subsample = sample(mydata,rep=T)
  hyperboot <- hyperbFit(subsample,hessian=FALSE)
  hyperboottransfparam<- hyperbChangePars(from=1,to=2,hyperboot$Theta)
  alpha[i]    = hyperboottransfparam[1]
  beta[i]    = hyperboottransfparam[2]
  delta[i] = hyperboottransfparam[3]
  mu[i] = hyperboottransfparam[4]

}
# hist(beta,breaks=100,xlim=c(-200,200))
sd(alpha)
sd(beta)
sd(delta)
sd(mu)
```

I get `119.6` for `sd(alpha)` and `35.85` for `sd(beta)`. The results are very different? Is there a mistake or what is the problem here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the following solution, I assume `hyperbPi` to be $\pi$. Also, the variances used in the approximations below are simply the squared standard errors calculated by `summary` after `hyperbFit`, so $\mathrm{Var}(X)=\mathrm{SE}(X)^2$. In order to calculate the approximation using the [delta-method](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme308/OldWebsite/notes/TaylorAppDeltaMethod.pdf), we need the partial derivatives of the transformation function s $g_{\alpha}(\zeta, \pi, \delta)$ and $g_{\beta}(\zeta, \pi, \delta)$. The transformation functions for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are given by:
$$
\begin{align}
    g_{\alpha}(\zeta, \pi, \delta) &=\frac{\zeta\sqrt{1 + \pi^{2}}}{\delta}\\
    g_{\beta}(\zeta, \pi, \delta)  &= \frac{\zeta\pi}{\delta}\\
\end{align}
$$
The partial derivatives of the transformation function for $\alpha$ are then:
$$
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta} g_{\alpha}(\zeta, \pi, \delta) &=\frac{\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}}{\delta}\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \pi} g_{\alpha}(\zeta, \pi, \delta)   &= \frac{\pi\zeta}{\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}\delta }\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \delta} g_{\alpha}(\zeta, \pi, \delta)   &= -\frac{\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}\zeta}{\delta^{2}}\\
\end{align}
$$
The partial derivatives of the transformation function for $\beta$ are:
$$
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta} g_{\beta}(\zeta, \pi, \delta) &=\frac{\pi}{\delta}\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \pi} g_{\beta}(\zeta, \pi, \delta)   &= \frac{\zeta}{\delta }\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \delta} g_{\beta}(\zeta, \pi, \delta)   &= -\frac{\pi\zeta}{\delta^{2}}\\
\end{align}
$$

Applying the [delta-method](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme308/OldWebsite/notes/TaylorAppDeltaMethod.pdf) to the transformations, we get the following approximation for the variance of $\alpha$ (take square roots to get the standard errors):
$$
\mathrm{Var}(\alpha)\approx \frac{1+\pi^{2}}{\delta^{2}}\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\zeta)+\frac{\pi^{2}\zeta^{2}}{(1+\pi^{2})\delta^{2}}\cdot  \mathrm{Var}(\pi) + \frac{(1+\pi^{2})\zeta^{2}}{\delta^{4}}\cdot  \mathrm{Var}(\delta) + \\
2\times \left[ \frac{\pi\zeta}{\delta^{2}}\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\pi,\zeta) - \frac{(1+\pi^{2})\zeta}{\delta^{3}}\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\delta,\zeta)- \frac{\pi\zeta^{2}}{\delta^{3}}\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\delta,\pi)\right]
$$
The approximated variance of $\beta$ is:

$$
\mathrm{Var}(\beta)\approx \frac{\pi^{2}}{\delta^{2}}\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\zeta) + \frac{\zeta^{2}}{\delta^{2}}\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\pi) + \frac{\pi^{2}\zeta^{2}}{\delta^{4}}\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\delta) + \\
2\times \left[ \frac{\pi\zeta}{\delta^{2}}\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\pi,\zeta) - \frac{\pi^{2}\zeta}{\delta^{3}}\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\delta, \zeta) - \frac{\pi\zeta^{2}}{\delta^{3}}\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\pi, \delta) \right]
$$

---

**Coding in `R`**

The fastest way to calculate the above approximations is using matrices. Denote $D$ the row vector containing the partial derivatives of the transformation function for $\alpha$ or $\beta$ with respect to $\zeta, \pi, \delta$. Further, denote $\Sigma$ the $3\times 3$ variance-covariance matrix of $\zeta, \pi, \delta$. The covariance matrix can be retrieved by typing `vcov(my.hyperbFit)` where `my.hyperbFit` is the fitted function. The above approximation of the variance of $\alpha$ is then
$$
\mathrm{Var}(\alpha)\approx D_{\alpha}\Sigma D_{\alpha}^\top
$$
The same is true for the approximation of the variance of $\beta$.

In `R`, this can be easily coded like this:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The row vector D of the partial derivatives for alpha
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

D.alpha <- matrix(
  c(
    sqrt(1+pi^2)/delta,                 # differentiate wrt zeta
    ((pi*zeta)/(sqrt(1+pi^2)*delta)),   # differentiate wrt pi
    -(sqrt(1+pi^2)*zeta)/(delta^2)      # differentiate wrt delta
  ),
  ncol=3)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The row vector D of the partial derivatives for beta
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

D.beta <- matrix(
  c(
    (pi/delta),            # differentiate wrt zeta
    (zeta/delta),          # differentiate wrt pi
    -((pi*zeta)/delta^2)   # differentiate wrt delta
  ),
  ncol=3)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Calculate the approximations of the variances for alpha and beta
# "sigma" denotes the 3x3 covariance matrix
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var.alpha <- D.alpha %*% sigma %*% t(D.alpha) 
var.beta <- D.beta %*% sigma %*% t(D.beta)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The standard errors are the square roots of the variances
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

se.alpha <- sqrt(var.alpha)
se.beta <- sqrt(var.beta)
```

---

### Using $\log(\zeta)$ and $\log(\delta)$

If the standard errors/variances are only available for $\zeta^{*}=\log(\zeta)$ and $\delta^{*}=\log(\delta)$ instead of $\zeta$ and $\delta$, the transformation functions change to:
$$
\begin{align}
    g_{\alpha}(\zeta^{*}, \pi, \delta^{*}) &=\frac{\exp(\zeta^{*})\sqrt{1 + \pi^{2}}}{\exp(\zeta^{*})}\\
    g_{\beta}(\zeta^{*}, \pi, \delta^{*})  &= \frac{\exp(\zeta^{*})\pi}{\exp(\delta^{*})}\\
\end{align}
$$
The partial derivatives of the transformation function for $\alpha$ are then:
$$
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta^{*}} g_{\alpha}(\zeta^{*}, \pi, \delta^{*}) &=\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \pi} g_{\alpha}(\zeta^{*}, \pi, \delta^{*}) &=\frac{\pi\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})}{\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \delta^{*}} g_{\alpha}(\zeta^{*}, \pi, \delta^{*}) &=-\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})\\
\end{align}
$$
The partial derivatives of the transformation function for $\beta$ are:
$$
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta^{*}} g_{\beta}(\zeta^{*}, \pi, \delta^{*}) &=\pi\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \pi} g_{\beta}(\zeta^{*}, \pi, \delta^{*}) &=\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \delta^{*}} g_{\beta}(\zeta^{*}, \pi, \delta^{*}) &=-\pi\exp(-\delta^{*}+\zeta^{*})\\
\end{align}
$$
Applying the [delta-method](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme308/OldWebsite/notes/TaylorAppDeltaMethod.pdf) to the transformations, we get the following approximation for the variance of $\alpha$:
$$
\mathrm{Var}(\alpha)\approx (1+\pi^{2})\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\zeta^{*})+\frac{\pi^{2}\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})}{1+\pi^{2}}\cdot  \mathrm{Var}(\pi) + (1+\pi^{2})\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\delta^{*}) + \\
2\times \left[ \pi\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\pi,\zeta^{*}) - (1+\pi^{2})\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\delta^{*},\zeta^{*}) - \pi\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\delta^{*},\pi)\right]
$$
The approximated variance of $\beta$ is:
$$
\mathrm{Var}(\beta)\approx \pi^{2}\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\zeta^{*})+\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\pi) + \pi^{2}\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\delta^{*}) + \\
2\times \left[\pi\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*}) \cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\pi,\zeta^{*}) -\pi^{2}\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\delta^{*},\zeta^{*}) -\pi\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*}) \cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\delta^{*},\pi)\right]
$$

---

**Coding in `R` 2**

This time, `sigma` denotes the covariance matrix but including the variances and covariances for $\zeta^{*}=\log(\zeta)$ and $\delta^{*}=\log(\delta)$ instead of $\zeta$ and $\delta$.

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The row vector D of the partial derivatives for alpha
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

D.alpha <- matrix(
  c(
    sqrt(1+pi^2)*exp(-ldelta + lzeta),            # differentiate wrt lzeta
    ((pi*exp(-ldelta + lzeta))/(sqrt(1+pi^2))),   # differentiate wrt pi
    (-sqrt(1+pi^2)*exp(-ldelta + lzeta))          # differentiate wrt ldelta
  ),
  ncol=3)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The row vector D of the partial derivatives for beta
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

D.beta <- matrix(
  c(
    (pi*exp(-ldelta + lzeta)),    # differentiate wrt lzeta
    exp(-ldelta + lzeta),         # differentiate wrt pi
    (-pi*exp(-ldelta + lzeta))    # differentiate wrt ldelta
  ),
  ncol=3)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Calculate the approximations of the variances for alpha and beta
# "sigma" denotes the 3x3 covariance matrix with log(delta) and log(zeta)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var.alpha <- D.alpha %*% sigma %*% t(D.alpha) 
var.beta <- D.beta %*% sigma %*% t(D.beta)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The standard errors are the square roots of the variances
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

se.alpha <- sqrt(var.alpha)
se.beta <- sqrt(var.beta)
```

Comment: @JenBohold No problem. Please ask if you have further questions.

Comment: one more question: How do you get the terms in the [] brackets before the Cov() ? What are those terms?

Comment: @BenBohold The terms inside the brackets before the covariance terms are the products of the respective partial derivatives of the transformation functions. For example: The term before $\mathrm{Cov}(\pi, \zeta)$ is the product of the partial derivative wrt $\pi$ multiplied by the partial derivative wrt $\zeta$. In the case of $\beta$ this would be: $\zeta/\delta \times \pi/\delta = (\zeta\cdot\pi)/\delta^{2}$.

Comment: one more question: I tried to apply vcov to the hyperbfit variable, but it does not work? I tried vcov(hyperbfitalv) where hyperbfitalv is defined in the following way: hyperbfitalv<-hyperbFit(mydata,hessian=TRUE)

I get the (german) error message:
Fehler in UseMethod("vcov") : 
  nicht anwendbare Methode für 'vcov' auf Objekt der Klasse "hyperbFit" angewendet

Comment: also applied to summary it does not work: vcov(summary(hyperbfitalv))

Comment: @BenBohold Strange, but no problem. Try to calculate the covariance matrix in this way: `varcov <- solve(hyperbfitalv$hessian)`. Does this work? After that, you will have to select the sub-matrix containing only $\pi, \zeta, \delta$. The easiest way I could help you would be if you provided a fully working example with data (you don't have to provide all your data).

Comment: A big thanks for your answer, but this is EXACTLY the problem, because the parameterization of this hessian is for log(delta) and log(zeta) and not for delta and zeta! See my follow-up posts: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67595/variance-covariance-matrix-of-the-parameter-estimates-wrongly-calculated and especially the answer of CT Zhu here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67602/the-vcov-function-cannot-be-applied

Comment: one has to get the hessian of pi, log(zeta), log(delta), and mu into the hessian of pi, zeta, delta, and mu. Do you know how this could be done?

Comment: I also tried to do it with the "wrong" hessian, so with log(delta) and log(zeta), after this I selected the sub-matrix and did the calculations. The results were not correct, because the values were way too large, so like 60 000 or so.

Comment: @JenBohold Jen, I updated my answer including the case when you only have $\log(\delta)$ and $\log(\zeta)$. I think you can now use the Hessian of the original parametrization (logs), calculate the variance-covariance matrix from that and apply the delta method. Could you give it a try and see if it produces some sensible results?

Comment: one more question: What should I insert for zeta* delta* and pi? The parameter estimates? Because I only have the parameter estimates for pi, zeta and delta, but not for log(zeta) and log(delta)? I guess for pi I insert the parameter estimate for pi and for zeta* and delta* I insert the log value of the parameter estimates, correct?

Comment: @JenBohold Jup, just use `log(zeta)` and `log(delta)`. The `hyperbFit` just prints out `exp(log(zeta))` and `exp(log(delta))`.

Comment: I edited my question and implemented your code and I show the results. What do you think? Did I implement it correctly and are the results reliable, especially why is there such a big difference to the results of the bootstrap algorithm? What should I use, bootstrap or delta-method? I think both inherit the problem of instability of the ML estimates, right?

Comment: @JenBohold Your implementation seems correct. The reason why the bootstrap standard errors are so much bigger is that there are some very high values among the bootstrap samples (I repeated your bootstrap with $B=10000$). The mean of my bootstrap samples are $104.7$ for $\alpha$ and $2.15$ for $\beta$ which are also much larger than the values obtained by `hyperbChangePars` ($73.95$ and $0.052$). So both the mean and SD are influenced by some very high values among the bootstrap samples. To be honest, I don't know which method is "better". (contd).

Comment: @JenBohold (condt): The delta-method is an approximation whereas the bootstrap takes your data into account without assuming any distribution. I honestly don't know what to recommend as both methods have their drawbacks. Maybe someone else could shed more light on the matter ...

Comment: @JenBohold One additional thing: I also implemented your bootstrap but using the `boot` package. After that, I calculated the BCa-confidence intervals for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. For $\alpha$ the 95%-BCa-CI is $(55.25, 154.14)$ and for $\beta$ $(-22.15, 24.89)$. The naive 95%-CIs using the standard error of the delta-method are $(48.11, 99.79)$ for $\alpha$ and $(-13.56, 13.66)$ for $\beta$. The bootstrap CIs are wider, as they incorporate the shape of the data. This is expected.

Comment: Well, everything is fine then somehow, since the implementations are correct. Again: A very BIG thanks for your ongoing support, especially for helping me out with the vcov problem!

Comment: @JenBohold No problem, thank you for the bounty :) You may consider opening a new question about which method to use. Maybe you'll get some good responses.

Comment: Ok one more last question: You say delta-method assumes a certain distribution, what distribution does it assume?

Comment: @JenBohold Sorry, my phrasing was sloppy: The first-order Talyor approximation (the one we used here) converges to a normal distribution. One caveat that could occur is when the first order approximation, which is linear, isn't very good because the approximated function is highly nonlinear. Then the first-order delta-method doesn't work and a higher order Taylor series may be considered.

Answer (score -2):

Possible duplicate: [Standard errors of hyperbFit?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55714/standard-errors-of-hyperbfit)

I could bet some accounts belong to the same person ...

Comment: I already linked that thread in my post! And if you really read my question you will see, that I DO NOT WANT TO use the bootstrap algorithm, but I am asking about the delta-method.